# Rasa chat bot deployed on Heroku not responding to chat, only working on localhost 127.0.0.1:5000

Tags: docker, heroku, deployment, chatbot, rasa

I have created a rasa chat bot that is working properly on my system. chat response below[image]

But when I deployed It on the Heroku the bot is not responding. chat responses below
[image]

Here is my code link [GitHub code repository](https://github.com/engineerbasit/rasalovesflask) and Heroku deployed app link
[Heroku link](https://rasaflask.herokuapp.com/)

Can anyone tell me what is problem with this?

I have used docker image to manage dependencies but I think my model is not properly deployed. I want to get an answer from the model.

Comment: Ensure your rasa running ports are open to public.

Answer (score 0):

Your project relies on 2 open ports. This is not possible with Heroku because your webbrowser clients make a connection with your flask app in the browser and have to send API calls to your rasa action server.

1 port is used for the rasa action server.
1 port is used for your flask app.

Your rasa action server declared in `start_services.sh` is never started.

Put your rasa action server in a separate Heroku app. Point the API endpoint calls of your flask app to that new Heroku app.